# How to interpolate anchor tag in a text in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a variable

```
const linkElement = `Hey this is a link ${<a href="www.google.com">Click me!</a>} that can be clicked}`
```

This renders as Hey this is a link [Object object] that can be clicked.

How can I render this like,
Hey this is a link Click me!(on click goes to google.com) that can be clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to wrap your text inside a react component. A React component cannot be part of a string as it has no concept of a react component.

example:

```js
LinkElement = () => <span>
  Hey this is a link <a href="www.google.com">Click me!</a> that can be clicked
<span>

//and the place you want to use it
<LinkElement />
```

Comment: Surrounded it with a <span>, and it worked like charm!

Comment: great! Would appreciate if you select it as the solving answer if thats the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
const linkElement = <>Hey this is a link<a href="www.google.com">Click me !</a> that can be clicked</>
```

Comment: Oooo - that's very nice - thanks!